# Installing Theano on Windows 10 - error when importing theano

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I've followed numerous installation tutorials for windows over the past few days. I use anaconda on windows 10. But I always get the following error when importing theano:

```
. collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status C:\Users\Cedric     
Oeldorf\Anaconda3\libs/python35.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
```

Could anyone help me out on this?

I have run

```
conda install mingw libpython
```

Comment: you are using python 3 aren't you?

Comment: Yes 3.5 shouldn't I be?